# Can I convert this subquery containing an INNER JOIN into a LEFT JOIN, or otherwise flatten it?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, not-exists

Still learning Oracle SQL, so I'll do my best to word this clearly.

In the following, I'm filtering out data using NOT EXISTS with a subselect, but I need to convert it to a join if possible. I'm assuming that this would involve a LEFT JOIN, but the additional INNER JOIN in the subselect is tripping me up.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON     table1.user_id = table2.user_id
AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM   table3
           INNER JOIN table4
           ON     table4.event_id = table3.event_id
           WHERE  table3.status_id = table2.status_id
)
```

How can I retrieve the exact same results without relying on a subselect?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the subquery? It seems like a relevant way to phrase the query.

Comment: Weird policy doesn't allow for it.

Comment: A policy against subqueries?  That is weird, because it makes no sense.

Comment: Can you use "MINUS" ?  It will look silly but i think:  [your example up thru 'AND'] MINUS [inner join all the tables]   would be same results?

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

`not exists` and a subquery is the right tool for this job.

I suppose what you had in mind is to rewrite it as two `LEFT JOIN`s and a `WHERE` clause to filter on unmatched record only:

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN  table3 t2 ON t3.status_id = t2.status_id
LEFT JOIN  table4 t4 ON t4.event_id = t3.event_id
WHERE t4.event_id IS NULL
```

But this is not equivalent to the original: if a record has two matches in `tabl3` and no matches in `table4`, you will get duplicates in the resultset.

That's kind of a dumb workaround, but would the said policy allow a lateral join?

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 1 flag
    FROM table3 t3
    INNER JOIN table4 ON t4.event_id = t3.event_id
    WHERE  t3.status_id = t2.status_id
) x 
WHERE x.flag IS NULL
```

Comment: Yeah, that first example is close to what I had in mind originally, and just as you said, I was getting a lot of duplicates.

Unfortunately, a lateral join won't be allowed. These are admittedly very odd constraints, but my hands are tied.

Comment: @Nitroid: Maybe a CTE (but that's a subquery in essence)? Expressing what you want without a derived table seems challenging.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty simple example of anti-join:

```sql
SELECT table1.*,table2.* 
FROM   table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON     table1.user_id = table2.user_id
left JOIN(
           SELECT distinct table3.status_id
           FROM   table3
           INNER JOIN table4
           ON     table4.event_id = table3.event_id
    ) t3
    ON t3.status_id = table2.status_id
where t3.status_id is null;
```

Oracle optimizer makes such transformation for you itself, if it considers such transformation more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using bracketing:

```
select *
from   table1
       join table2
            on  table2.user_id = table1.user_id
       left join ( table3 join table4 on table4.event_id = table3.event_id ) 
            on  table3.status_id = table2.status_id
where  table4.event_id is null;
```

I can't test this properly as I don't have your data. There could be problems if the table3/table4 join returned multiple rows per table1/table2, as then you would get more rows than your original query.